# Ubuntu 14.04 - Force using home and end as keyboard shortcuts

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to be able to use the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys as shortcuts, but Ubuntu's settings absolutely refuse to let you do so by normal means because it'll become "impossible to type using this key." - That's just silly. I personally never use those keys; I'm sure some people do, but I am not one of them.

Is there a way to possibly force Ubuntu to allow you to rebind these keys or a workaround that allows you to do so?
(I apologize for asking this here, but AskUbuntu requires you to have an account to ask questions whereas Unix&Linux does not. <3)

Comment: the markup used for `Home` and `End` (`<kbd></kbd>`) already implies that they are keys, so adding the word keys is like talking about Personal PIN numbers and or other [RAS syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome) effects.

Answer (score 0):

Remap the keys to something else then use them.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices has some good instructions. But basically you use xmodmap to remap the home and end keys to someting like F13 and F14 then map them to shortcut keys normally.